# Why does the following sqlcmd call returns 0 rows when in a bat file? (passing manually)

Tags: sql, batch-file, scripting, sqlcmd

I am having trouble writing up a batch script. I've narrowed it down to what seems to break and I am providing an example. The following code, when pasted into a console returns 10 rows:

```
set TESTRUNID=111222
set QUERY="select distinct col1 from Table where col2='%TESTRUNID%' and col3 LIKE '%es'"
start /B /wait sqlcmd -S dahost -U usr -P pwd -Q %QUERY% -o resfile.txt
```

When I put it in a batch script, it returns 0 rows!

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
REM remark
REM remark
set TESTRUNID=111222
set QUERY="select distinct col1 from Table where col2='%TESTRUNID%' and col3 LIKE '%es'"
start /B /wait sqlcmd -S dahost -U usr -P pwd -Q %QUERY% -o resfile.txt
```

Comment: I can't answer your question, but your `WHERE` clause looks fishy to me.  I think it should read `where testrunid LIKE '%TESTRUNID%'`.  Why would an ID have literal percent signs in it?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the %% are for the batch scripting engine to parse TESTRUNID as the value defined in the line above

Comment: What about `%es` - which only has one `%`

Comment: @doctorlove that is for the SQL query, it means a wildcard for the LIKE functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing up the use of the percent sign to mean (1) batch variable expansion, and (2) SQL wildcard. Inside a batch file, use a double %% sign for an SQL wildcard:

```
set QUERY="select distinct col1 from Table where col2='%TESTRUNID%' and col3 LIKE '%%es'"
```

The double % sign gets translated to a single % sign before it's passed to SQLCMD.

Comment: yeah, I had just figured it out from a comment someone made. I tried your solution and it works fine! Thanks!
I am confused about what am I escaping here? the sqlcmd parsing engine or the batch script parsing engine?
If batch script thinks this is a variable, it should have tried to resolve it (and reach null in this case)

Comment: Batch scripts unfortunately have some unintuitive behaviours. When they find a single %, they ignore it. The same command would work fine with a single % if you had typed in on the command line.

Comment: Mind=blown. Thanks